# In what situations is it better to use a float over a double in Java?

Tags: java, performance, double

More specifically, how extreme is the performance gain when using a float instead of a double in Java?

Comment: It depends. As with all performance questions, **measure it.**

Comment: I believe all processors treat floats as doubles when actually performing the calculations.  The only difference would be memory footprint.

Comment: Mainly when you have a (very) large array of them, and double precision is not required.  Performance-wise there's not likely to be much difference, and double may actually be faster.

Comment: If Java is being run on a processor that doesn't have a floating-point unit at all, or supports 32-bit floats but not 64-bit floats, then a `float` could be faster.  I believe there are some PowerPC chips that don't have floating-point (so it has to be done in software), and Analog Devices 21xxx may not have 64-bit floats but I can't find the manual right now so I'm not sure.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo I'm getting a 404 on that link. Can you check it?

Comment: @chrylis Thanks. I will just write it out as an answer. The link has an apostrophe and is effing the whole thing up.

Comment: @chrylis I wrote it out as an answer. See if the link works for you now. It should.

Comment: @HotLicks: I beg to differ. Some time ago I wrote some numeric program where double were 3 times slower than floats. They need twice as much memory and didn't fit in the cache anymore (and the memory access locality was rather bad).

Comment: @maaartinus - Depends on the hardware.  In some cases double is faster than float.

Comment: @HotLicks: Sure... it was a modern Intel or AMD some maybe 8 years ago. I've also read that double was faster and could even confirm it experimentally. But for the whole program the cost of the computation was strongly dominated by memory misses.

Comment: Also some models of the Power processor.  Took extra cycles to expand a float into double for processing in the FP processor, then compress back to float.  And the effect of memory misses depends greatly on the cache design.  Machines that are inherently 64 bit will perform much better with wide operands.

Comment: How come this was marked as opinion-based? The question is specifically about performance, so it's measurable with scientific methods, so seems there is little to opinionate here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your question is mostly about performance, this article presents you with some specific calculations (keep in mind though that this article is specific to neural networks, and your calculations may be completely different to what they're doing in the article): http://web.archive.org/web/20150310213841/http://www.heatonresearch.com/content/choosing-between-java%E2%80%99s-float-and-double

Some of the relevant material from the link is reproduced here:

> Both double and float can support relatively large numbers. The upper
>   and lower range are really not a consideration for neural networks.
>   Float can handle numbers between 1.40129846432481707e-45 to
>   3.40282346638528860e+38...Basically, float can handle about 7 decimal places. A double can handle about 16 decimal places.
>
> Matrix multiplication is one of the most common mathematical
>   operations for neural network programming. By no means is it the only
>   operation, but it will provide a good benchmark. The following program
>   will be used to benchmark a double.

Skipping all the code, the table on the website shows that for a 100x100 matrix multiplication, they have a gain in performance of around 10% if they use doubles. For a 500x100 matrix multiplication, the performance loss because of using doubles is around 7%. And for a 1000x1000 matrix multiplication, that loss is around 17%.

> For the small 100x100 matrix switching to float may actually decrease
>   performance. As the size of the matrix increases, the percent gain
>   increases. With a very large matrix the performance gain increases to
>   17%. 17% is worth considering.

Answer (score 10):

**Normally**, I would use a `double`, because `float` doesn't have sufficient accuracy for many numerical use cases, and the performance difference is small enough not to matter.

As always, performance is implementation dependent so you will need to benchmark on your particular case in order to determine if it "matters" or not.

In general I have found:

- The performance difference for individual operations is pretty small, especially on 64-bit machines. Both a `float` and a `long` will fit in a 64-bit machine word. Often there is zero difference.
- `float`s have a slight advantage in that they consume less memory, and this can help with reducing CPU cache pressure. I've found floats to be 30-50% faster when doing simple operations over large arrays.

Comment: Are these performance gains on a 64-bit or 32-bit machine?  What sized arrays?

Comment: @Gray I think this gain can be achieved on both 32 and 64 bit systems, since L1 cache (and others) can comprise twice more float numbers than double ones. Hence we can achieve perfomance boost by reducing memory seek delay. But (IMO) java's libs designed to be more often used with doubles (double casts in many operation), thats why we cannot see this perfomance gain every time we change all doubles to floats in source code.

Answer (score 2):

Why `int` instead of `long`?

Why `short` instead of `int`?

Why `byte` instead of `short`?

This is all about performance and memory use reasons. In theory, more range means more memory, more memory needs more from your hardware and it means that more battery will be used.

Today's machines have high performance with primitive types. So, after all, you may not see any difference if you use long instead of double and vice versa, but, Internet Connections can be slow depending of the country, so it is best use the float instead of double in this case.

Lets talk about `short` vs `int`.

Short use less memory than `int`, but it takes 30% more time to be created (Java), so would be better aways use `int` instead of `short`? Depends, an array with 100 `short`s will use a much less memory than an array of 100 `int`s.

A loop with `short` can be more more efficient than a loop with `int`.

On internet, `short` is much more efficient than `int`, doens't matter if it takes 30% more to be created, the bandwith will be small and the experience will be better.

I'd sugest you to use only what you'll need. Remember: why 80 if 8 can do it?

Comment: short in java will be autonatically converted to int. a short needs 4 bytes, like an int. (except in arrays)

Comment: "more memory needs more from your hardware, it means that more battery will be used" - are you sure with this? As far as I know, memory usage does not impact power consumption. A 0 takes a much energy to store as a 1.

Comment: @SteveKuo, creating 1000 of double needs more from the RAM than creating 1000 of ints, this wouldn't have inpact on power consumption? Even if both stores 0?

Comment: Why does a short take 30% more time to be created?  Do you have a source for that assertion?

Comment: Reading a `double` from memory uses about twice as much energy as reading a `float` according to a [talk](http://sites.ieee.org/scv-cs/files/2013/03/Right-SizingPrecision1.pdf) from John Gustafson and this seems quite natural.

Comment: Steve, you are totally right about memory and power consumption but doesn't switching 0 to 1 and vice versa cost more CPU cycles hence the more power consumption ? I think this is why if we are confirmed we won't need those extra range of numbers, it is probably good to declare sufficient data type.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly at Embedded Systems without a CPU having fast double operations.
Eg navigation systems, with cpu intensive calculations.
But in java many Math libs implicitly convert to double, so in many cases it makes little sense to use float.

floats need half the memory, and advantage if you have very huge arrays and limited memory (in embedded devices)

Answer (score 1):

There are two conditions that should be met to use float instead of double:

1. There is a significant, useful performance gain.
2. Float is precise enough for the calculation in question.

Evaluating the first condition is relatively simple and easy. Measure the job using double. Measure again, with the same inputs and other conditions, using float. Is the float version significantly faster? Generally, the main benefit comes from more efficient use of caches, memory, and data transfer bandwidth.

The difficult part is evaluating the second condition. Getting insufficiently precise answers, or even wrong answers, is useless. For many calculations, relatively simple analysis can show double is precise enough. Showing the same for float is often much harder.

Comment: Have you run these tests yourself?  I suspect that the performance improve is much more tenuous if at all.

Comment: @Gray I have not so far had a good case for `float` in my own code. I did work with a customer who got a significant gain from `float` in doing transformations on very large arrays of seismic data. The gain came from the more efficient use of I/O, memory, memory access bandwidth, and data caches.